# Android studio not recognizing View variables and showing them as fields?

Tags: android, android-studio

Im having this problem recently where android studio is not recognizing any view variables and I cannot implement any operation on the field via id...its showing them as field and I have no idea  how to solve it !

**for example :**

```
TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.names);
```

I cannot implement any action such as set Text etc on the 'name' variable as it is indicating it as a field

Comment: clean and build again.

Comment: <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:background="@drawable/one"/>

Answer (score 0):

It seems your project is not compiled and build properly. That's why it is not compiling your view and other Android library classes. Consider rebuilding it and make sure build complete successfully.